# How can I download the video in mp3 format?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I want to download the first result as an audio file

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        try:
            requests.get(url) 
        except:
            video = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{search}")['entries'][0]
        else:
            video = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `ydl_opts` options:

```py
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }]
}
```

For more options see [file](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L137-L312)